# Kubernetes HPA and Performance Test

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, gatling, high-availability, hpa

I am doing a performance test against an API on a rate 50 requests per second.
and the pod resource limit is configured as
CPU : 300m
Memory: 512M

There is an HPA which triggers at 80 percentage.
Looks like without limit the pod takes upto 2GB of memory (service is handling memory intensive workload).
The idea is to limit memory as above - but HPA will be triggered and will save from pod eviction and all requests should be served.
However, with 50 req/s rate - scale out may not be fast enough to serve all the requests and can ultimately end up in 503.
Do we have any suggestions to handle such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

There are various reason why you end up in 503. But, what I suggest is to lower the HPA triggers to 50% or below so that your deployment will scale up earlier before it becomes too busy. Another option is to increase the node size, your node might experience over utilization due to memory intensive workload.